# Adding an input file when creating a payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, module, payment-methods

It's been a while since I want a way to add file upload system when creating a payment method.

In a custom module , I created a new method of payment. When declaring my fields in the file "system.xml" I'll wish to add an input to upload a PDF.
Here is part of my code :

```
<bvr translate="label" module="paygate">
   .......
   ....
   <fields>
      <bvrfile translate="label">
         <label>BVR file</label>
         <frontend_type>file</frontend_type>
         <sort_order>2</sort_order>
         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
         <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
      </bvrfile>
    </fields>
    .......
    ....
</bvr>
```

Here is a screenshot of my admin panel:
[image]

Do you know if it is possible to add this type of field and how I can retrieve the file's URL upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File will be saved in the **media** folder.

you have to specify the file path in `system.xml` by following code

```
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_file</backend_model>
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media/" scope_info="1">admin-config-uploads</upload_dir>
```

here the file will be save in the `root/media/<store_code>/admin-config-uploads/`

so to get the file path use the following code

```
<?php
    echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'admin-config-uploads'.Mage::getStoreConfig('system_config_name/group/upload_file');
?>
```

Refer this [**link**](http://www.kathirvel.com/adding-file-uploads-to-magento-admin-system-configuration/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like an hot cake !! ;)
I'm not able to change the destination folder like you describe.

but it does not matter.

thanks a lot for your reply & your help